# Is it possible to update from an action/method other than the update action/method in Ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

Is it possible to update from an action/method other than the update action/method?
For example in my users controller I already have an update method for other parts of my users account.

I need a separate one for changing my users password. Is it possible to have something like this:

```
def another_method_to_update
  user = User.authenticate(current_user.email, params[:current_password])
  if user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    login user
    format.js   { render :js => "window.location = '#{settings_account_path}'" } 
    flash[:success] = "Password updated" 
  else
    format.js   { render :form_errors }

  end
end
```

Then have my change password form know to use that method to perform the update?

It has 3 fields:
current password
new password
confirm new password

and I use ajax to show the form errors.

Kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can:

Add this in routes.rb:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    put :another_method_to_update
  end
end
```

In the view, you have to use the following URL:

```
another_method_to_update_user_path(@user)
```

Comment: It's for Rails 2. Throw `map.` away.

Comment: I'm now getting undefined method `another_method_to_update_user_path

Comment: Have you restarted the server? Can you please post your code - routes, controller & view?